# mysql syntax, select by only numbers

Tags: mysql

I would like to select all rows witch one contain 1234(numbers) in number column,
but including the numbers with "-" or "()" end excluding 12345 and 12-345.

```
numbers.
 --------------
| id | number  |
 --------------
| 1  | 1234    |
| 2  | 12-24   |
| 3  | 12(34)  |
| 4  | 1-2--34 |
| 5  | 12345   |
| 6  | 12-345  |
 --------------
```

Thanks for clue and idea.

Comment: why you need to exclude 12-345 if you want to include numbers with "-"?

Comment: because 12-34 is not same as 12-3 or 123.

Comment: I would like clear all signs (etc. -, (,)) from number column (live only numbers) and then select row by number.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL support for regular expressions is very limited, but this should return the correct result:

```
SELECT *
FROM   numbers
WHERE  number REGEXP "^(1|2|3|4|-|[[.left-parenthesis.]]|[[.right-parenthesis.]])*$"
```

Please see here for a [reference about regexps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), and here for an [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/461a32/1).